# How to add the formula of ram calculate price for eos in our project?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosjs, eosio.token, blockchains

Actually I am building an application and I would like to add the ram calculation for eos there. if anyone wants to calculate the ram for the accounts creation, he can use our website.thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from EOS NY's [eosrp.io](https://www.eosrp.io/#calc) to calculate RAM price from the API request below:

https://github.com/eosnewyork/erp/blob/master/backend/batchpriceupdater/src/com/eosrp/resources/EosResources.java#L90

---

This is some info I wrote up about the formula:

[What is the Bancor algorithm and how it is used for RAM trading?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1317/what-is-the-bancor-algorithm-and-how-it-is-used-for-ram-trading/)

```
cleos -u https://nodes.get-scatter.com:443 get table eosio eosio rammarket


{
  "rows": [{
      "supply": "10000000000.0000 RAMCORE",
      "base": {
        "balance": "11870290976 RAM",
        "weight": "0.50000000000000000"
      },
      "quote": {
        "balance": "5789275.3804 EOS",
        "weight": "0.50000000000000000"
      }
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```